Can I control Neopixel LEDs with this circuit? Is this a viable level shifter?
I recently purchased a microcontroller board (Pimoroni's Automation 2040 W) and I would like to control Neopixel-like LED strips (WS2815) which work with 12V. Since I am using a 3.3V microcontroller (RP2040) I wanted to use this board's sourcing outputs to control it.
This is the board's circuit with the current-sourcing outputs:

Where V+ is 12V.
Could you help me understand this circuit and figure out if it is capable of controlling the LEDs, please?
From my limited experience, I have made the following assumptions, if you can please comment on any or all of these assumptions so I can learn:

When the microcontroller sends a logic 1, the Mosfet Q7 connects V+, R22 and R23 to GND, causing the LED strip to... receive a 0?
When the microcontroller sends a logic 0, the current flows through R22 to the gate of Q4 and thus a 1 to the LED strip.
This circuit is called current sourcing because it keeps a constant current.
Such constant current depends on the value of V+, varying this volatge will increase or decrease the current on the LED strip. It's gonna be 12V so how does this affect the LEDs and how long the strip can be?
The Schottky diode D14 is there in case I connect a motor instead of LED strips, the board is protected against reverse currents.
R23 is there to prevent the transistor's inrush current spikes when there's switching. Under this logic, shouldn't there also be a resistor in series at the gain of Q7?
The resistor in series with LED18 is a pull-down resistor. Shouldn't this value be higher?
The zener diode D13 is there to... clamp the voltage?
The resistor R22 connects the gate and the drain so the mosfet Q4 is always active unless Q7 is activated by the uC. It is a resistor and not just a wire perhaps to draw current?

I probably said some absurd things but I am not an electrical engineer. I'm just trying to figure out if I can use this circuit as a level shifter.
I appreciate all the help you can give.
Edit: This table says it needs 70% of VDD to be a 1 and 30% of VDD to be a 0, so logic 1 would be 8.4V and 0 would be 3.6. Is this not right?

Above all, I'd like to understand this circuit and how it behaves.

Do you want to switch the power on and off to the LEDs (VDD) or just send the data (into DIN)? The WS2815 works with a constant voltage (12 V) on VDD and is not intended to be used with a constant current supply.

Maybe Voltage level shifter would be useful to you.

@Andrew Morton The LEDs will be powered directly from the power source, this is just to send the data into DIN, so if it is just the data I figured it was ok that the current is fixed although I am not sure if that much current is ok for the data pins.

The ws28xx chips all use 5v logic. Feeding 12v will destroy them.

That can sure control the power supply to any device such as regular LEDs and Neopixel-alike LEDs.
But if you want to level shift data from 3.3V supply to 5V to communicate data to these ARGB LEDs, there are already multiple questions and answers here how to do it properly.

@AndrewMorton This is a bug in the datasheet, they interchanged VDD and VCC in several positions. Expect VCC to be around 5 V and you just need a level shifter from 3.3 V to 5 V.

@Jens Ooh, that's a nasty documentation bug. Is that something that is widely known by everyone except the manufacturers?

@AndrewMorton It is just physics and marketing logic. You cannot simply transport a signal with >5 MHz bandwidth using 12V amplitude and the manufacturer would not produce a product, that uses the same signal timing but an incompatible signal amplitude compared to all the previous chips from that series. The header of the first table on page 3 specifies VDD as 4.5..5.5 V. That does not match the VDD voltage range fom 9.5..13.5 V in the table on the bottom of page 2. They just do not read their own datasheet.

@Jens I'm not sure that the datasheet is wrong, the table 'Electrical characteristics' mentions VDD=4.5~5.5V because that's the voltage they used to test and obtain that table. However, it should be supplied with 12V and the input Din should be 70% of VDD for it to be recognized as a logic 1

All these strips use 5V logic levels. You can use a 74HCT logic gate to translate from 3V3 to 5V. It is a good idea to also use a MOSFET on the 12V power supply because these LEDs draw substantial current even when they're off though.
